# Smart-table pagination throws error

Tags: smart-table

My page is successfully loading the smart-table js, but when I try to use the pagination feature (as shown in the documentation) I receive the following errors

```
http://localhost:47544/template/smart-table/pagination.html Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

and

```
Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.7/$compile/tpload?p0=template%2Fsmart-table%2Fpagination.html
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but below is my code. Any help would be great! Thanks!

```
<body>
<div ng-controller="testController as ctrl">
    <div>
        <div class="page-header"><h2>Table Test</h2></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-6">
                <table st-table="ctrl.myData" class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="10"><input st-search="" placeholder="Universal Search" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th st-sort="name">name</th>
                            <th st-sort="location">location</th>
                            <th st-sort="age">age</th>
                            <th st-sort="phone">phone</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th><input st-search="name" placeholder="Search" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" /></th>
                            <th><input st-search="location" placeholder="Search" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" /></th>
                            <th><input st-search="age" placeholder="Search" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" /></th>
                            <th><input st-search="phone" placeholder="Search" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" /></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="row in ctrl.myData">
                            <td>{{row.name}}</td>
                            <td>{{row.location}}</td>
                            <td>{{row.age}}</td>
                            <td>{{row.phone}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4" class="text-center">
                                <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="5" st-displayed-pages="3"></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-2 col-lg-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: what file have you included ? try <script src="path/to/smart-table.js"></script> normally the template is included in the $templateCache and the browser should not even try to get it (https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/blob/master/dist/smart-table.js)

Answer (score 0):

It is too late, but if someone faces the same issue you can check maybe you have simply called one of next methods somewhere and by this erased default pagination template from your cache.

```
$templateCache.destroy(); 
$templateCache.removeAll();
$templateCache.remove('template/smart-table/pagination.html');
```

[Check this documentation for info about methods](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$cacheFactory.Cache)